# Update null obects in a json array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Update null objects in a json array.

I had tried using map but it didn't updated for all the json objects

I had a json array like below

```
var response =
{
  "code": null,
  "message": "Total 1 records found",
  "result": {
    "ordersList": [
      {
        "testId": 134,
        "ordersDto": {
          "orderId": 51684,
          "reportses": [
            {
              "reportId": 472,
              "reportStatus": {
                "id": 10,
                "value": "Pending",
                "prevId": 9,
                "type": "R"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "testId": 134,
        "ordersDto": {
          "orderId": 51687,
          "reportses": [

          ],

        }
      },
      {
        "testId": 134,
        "ordersDto": {
          "orderId": 51689,
          "reportses": [

          ],

        }
      },

    ]
  }
}
```

If reports is null, then I need to update the report status of all the JSON object in the array

```
New Object =  "reportStatus": {
                "id": 10,
                "value": "Pending",
                "prevId": 9,
                "type": "R"
              }
```

After heupdate, it will return an array with the status.

```
var response =

{
  "code": null,
  "message": "Total 1 records found",
  "result": {
    "ordersList": [
      {
        "testId": 134,
        "ordersDto": {
          "orderId": 51684,
          "reportses": [
            {
              "reportId": 472,
              "reportStatus": {
                "id": 10,
                "value": "Pending",
                "prevId": 9,
                "type": "R"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "testId": 134,
        "ordersDto": {
          "orderId": 51687,
          "reportses": [
            {
              "reportStatus": {
                "id": 10,
                "value": "Pending",
                "prevId": 9,
                "type": "R"
              }
            }
          ],

        }
      },
      {
        "testId": 134,
        "ordersDto": {
          "orderId": 51689,
          "reportses": [
            {
              "reportStatus": {
                "id": 10,
                "value": "Pending",
                "prevId": 9,
                "type": "R"
              }
            }
          ],

        }
      },

    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not to just iterate over the object and update it?
What is the result you are trying to achive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code ( It is not tested )

```
response.result.ordersList.map(function(order){ 
  if(order.ordersDto.reportses.length === 0){ 
    order.ordersDto.reportses.push(newObjYouWantToPush) 
  }  
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This JavaScript snippet will help you in achieving the solution. The catch is to find the **size of the array** and push respective content if **size is zero**.

```js
for (i = 0; i < response.result.ordersList.length; i++) {
  if(response.result.ordersList[i].ordersDto.reportses.length === 0)
{
response.result.ordersList[i].ordersDto.reportses.push({
      "reportStatus": {
        "id": 10,
        "value": "Pending",
        "prevId": 9,
        "type": "R"
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: This code has been successfully tested in google chrome console.